# ec2-import-instance of VMWare vmdk of Windows OS success, but can't RDP access the new ec2 instance

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a virtual machine for CI/build (Subversion, Jenkins) environment running Windows Server 2008 inside a VMWare server 2.0. We are migrating to AWS EC2 so using ec2-import-instance command line tool.

Following steps were followed and import took 8 hours for 60GB to upload to S3 bucket.

1. Remove snapshot of the VM
2. Convert the vmdk file to Streaming (type 5) format under a new name.
3. import
   ec2-import-instance "D:/Virtual Machines/VM Source Control/VMServer4.vmdk" -f VMDK -t t1.micro -a x86_64 -b bucket.eu-west.vmimport -o  accesskey -w securitykey -g quicklaunch-1 --region eu-west-1 -z eu-west-1c
4. ec2-describe-conversion-tasks command with TaskID shows 'Completed' status.
5. A new EC2 instance is created and I started the instance from AWS Console.

When I try to remote desktop the new instance with the public DNS, the RDP can't find the instance (the quicklaunch-1 security group is already configured for other instances, and it works for my IP).

I had test imported another VM with windows, and I was able to access that ec2-instance (It had no snapshot created).

Could you please tell me what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember to do these things prior to converting your image:

1. To enable RDP via My Computer (right-click)->Settings->Advanced->Remote
2. To configure Windows internal firewall to access RDP

I was involved in creation of the tool to automate the process: http://www.migrate2iaas.com